# Port forwarding on ZTE router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, playstation

I'm trying to forward the following ports on my ZTE router (as per PlayStation's recommendations):

```
TCP: 80, 443, 3478, 3479, 3480
UDP: 3478, 3479
```

The manual for my router gives very limited information, as do my ISP (Hyperoptic)

Does anyone know what I need to enter into the fields in the screengrab? See link below

[image: ZTE Router]

Comment: What is the exact model of your router? Could you add a screenshot of your port-forwards? Have you checked the router's firewall? How do you see that forwarding does not work?

Comment: its a ZTE H298A. The firewall was originally on 'high' but i turned down to medium

Comment: ...Im not saying it doesnt work, Im just not sure how to open those ports using the form in the screengrab

Comment: Are you sure you want to FORWARD these ports, not OPEN them? The latter is default on all home routers I know, and it would really surprise me, if the playstation would want to have those ports FORWARED to it

Comment: Do not forward port 80 and 443. It's definitely not required. Also check whether you're behind CGNAT.

Comment: @EugenRieck ah I always thought they were the same thing!

Comment: @DanielB I am behind CGNAT yes, thats one thing my ISP mentioned although they didnt tell me how to get round it

Comment: FORWARDING a Port means, that connections from the *outside to* your public IP will be handled by a device on the *inside*, while OPENING a port means to allow a device on the *inside* to connect to the *outside*. Most home routers (including all ZTE I know of) do the latter for all ports anyway.

Comment: @EugenRieck I see! Thanks for clarifying. The connection problems that I have are still evident even when I plug my PS4 straight into the ethernet on the wall... does this mean attempting to change anything on the router is probably pointless?

Comment: Indeed I think so - most likely your CGNAT assigns you less than needed table slots resulting in single, long-standning connections to work well, while short-lived connections fail (the slots are recycled too slow)

Comment: @EugenRieck thanks... I imagine this is most likely just down to Hyperoptic then? Shame they are refusing to help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the manual
[Port forwarding for ZTE H298A](https://hyperoptic.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Port-forwarding-and-DMZ-for-ZTE-ZXHN-H298A-v1.3.pdf).

Basically this option is found in
*Internet > Security > Port Forwarding > Create New Item*.
Fill in the fields of Protocol type, WAN port and LAN Host port,
then click Apply.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how would I enter the TCP / UDP values I mentioned in my post?

Comment: WAN port is the port that is used from the internet. LAN Host port is the target port on the computer to which it is mapped. Both may be equal, which is probably your case.

Comment: so for TCP, would I enter '80, 443, 3478, 3479, 3480' into the WAN port and LAN Host port?